# Error's With AOSCompiler - CM10 - Galaxy Nexus/maguro

Tags: android, ubuntu, compiler-errors, adb, android-source

I trying to compile CM10 with AOSCompiler(using ubuntu). And i got 2 questions:

1.It's Saying me that it's can't find my device:

```
elichai@elichai-MT6840:~/.aoscompiler/build$ . build/envsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a/vendorsetup.sh
including device/ti/panda/vendorsetup.sh
including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
elichai@elichai-MT6840:~/.aoscompiler/build$ lunch cm_maguro-userdebug
build/core/product_config.mk:189: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/*/maguro/cm.mk]]:    "device/samsung/tuna/device.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
Device maguro not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod    Github (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
Found repository: android_device_samsung_maguro
CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_maguro already exists
Syncing repository to retrieve project.
Fetching projects: 100% (1/1), done.  

Repository synced!
Looking for dependencies
Done
build/core/product_config.mk:189: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/*/maguro/cm.mk]]:   "device/samsung/tuna/device.mk" does not exist.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_maguro'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

I tried to do just 'lunch' and choose my device from the list and it's gave me the same error.
I tried to use 'breakfast' and it's gave me the same error too.

2.The AOSCOmpiler Saying that:

> Adb isn't running
>   Need adb to setup vendor files.
>
> Is this something you are going to do yourself?
>
> Please try again.

Even i added to the file '/etc/bash.bashrc this line:

> export PATH=${PATH}:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/tools:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools

(this is my SDK location) and now i can use 'adb' without going to the SDK folder. but it's still not working(the AOSCompiler).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know it's getting old, but, to to the `export PATH=${PATH}:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/tools:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools` you should remove {}s
`export PATH=$PATH:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/tools:/home/elichai/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools`
That's what I did. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04

Also, you could add the paths to your .bashrc, assuming you are using bach as you shell.

I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.